# Connection refused with AWS public IP

Tags: angular, amazon-ec2, ubuntu-18.04

I'm using a Ubuntu 18.04 instance, I started the server using Nginx command:

```
sudo service nginx stop && sudo service nginx start
```

I'm getting the "Connection refused error" in the browser when I try to connect with public IP. I tried to check the Nginx status

I've allowed the port 80,443,22,4200 in security groups. This is my Nginx config:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://privateip:node_port;  
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
}
```

Comment: is your machine allowing connections on port 80? do this with `sudo ufw enable && ufw allow 80/tcp`

Comment: Where should I give this command??? In ubuntu server or in local cmd?

Comment: You should run the previous command on your Ubuntu Server. You should also check for your Network Access Control List (NACL) on the subnet.

Basically, an internet connection to an EC2 goes like this: Internet -> Inbound NACL filtering -> Inbound SG -> Server FW -> Outbound NACL -> Internet
There is no Outbound SG needed.

Comment: Yeah in NACL Inbound rule is set with rule 100, port - All, type - All Traffic

Comment: Yes execute ufw commands on Ubuntu server; we are trying to open ports on server

Comment: I'm getting this error Firewall is active and enabled on system startup
ERROR: You need to be root to run this script, when I run this command sudo ufw enable && ufw allow 80/tcp